# What's wrong with the boundary condition of this $1$st order ODE?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, boundary-value-problem, eigenfunctions

Consider the following $1$st order eigen ODE system of 2 components $(\alpha,\beta)(x)$ defined for $x\in[0,L]$
$$
F_{l+1}\beta+m\alpha=\lambda\alpha\\
F_{-l}\alpha-m\beta=\lambda\beta
$$
where $\lambda$ is the eigenvalue, $l$ is integer, $m(0)$ is finite and $m(L)\rightarrow\infty$, and $F_k=-i(\frac{d}{dx}+\frac{k}{x})$.

Since it is just $1$st order, I thought only 2 boundary conditions (b.c.) are necessary, which can be most easily taken as $(\alpha,\beta)(L)=0$ since $m(L)$ diverges. **So one doesn't need or just shouldn't involve  b.c. at $x=0$? Is this true?**

However, on the other hand, if I do the very simple asymptotic analysis at $x\rightarrow0$ for these equations, I find that 
$$
l\neq0,-1\qquad (\alpha,\beta)(0)=0\\
l=-1\qquad (\alpha,\beta')(0)=0
$$
with $l=0$ similar to $l=-1$. What I did is basically just noting that, when $k\neq0$, any component acted by $F_k$ is $0$ at $x=0$. And using this, we notice the other component's derivative vanishes. **It seems that b.c. at $x=0$ is natural as well.**

How to reconcile these two considerations? Where am I wrong?